# Ajax errorThrown: Internal Server Error but state is 4

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have this ajax call below

```
$(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/CafeTableDetails/GetTotalItems',
                 data: '{"url":"test"}',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger
                alert("some error");
                }
            });
        });
```

and it can call the action method of my controller in C# MVC `/CafeTableDetails/GetTotalItems`

```
    public ActionResult GetTotalItems()
    {
        bool isSuccess = true;
        return Json(new { isUpdateSuccess = isSuccess, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });

    }
```

But as the action method return it back as Json, it falls into `error`. The `XMLHttpRequest` return state is 4, `textStatus` = "Error" and `errorThrown` is "Internal Server Error". How do I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Does the serverside function actually get called?

Comment: yes, my server side function is called. But, when it return it back to the view, it hit "internal server error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax method should be :

```
 $.ajax({
          type: "GET", 
          url: "/CafeTableDetails/GetTotalItems",
          data: JSON.stringify({ url: 'test' }),
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          success: function(response) { 
              console.log(response); 
          },
          error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
              console.log(xhr.responseText); 
          }
        });
```

and your controller action method will be:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetTotalItems(string url)
{
    // some business logic and return
    return Json(url, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: You dont need to return JsonResult type

Comment: thanks. your code works although i don't know what I did wrong.